# Pythons' sleep() CPU usage

Tags: python, timer, load, cpu, sleep

How does Python handle its `sleep()` function? I want to create a clock which is ment to run like forever and print the time every 60 seconds and sleeps for the rest of the time. Does Python use CPU time while sleeping?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, sleep() does not use CPU time in python (or in any other programming language that I've heard of). Other alternatives for achieving similar results include [sched](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html)-module, twisteds [LoopingCall](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/8.1.0/api/twisted.internet.task.LoopingCall.html) or GLibs Timeout.

Note that any method that includes waiting for a constant amount of time (like sleep()) will in the long run drift compared to an actual timeout API (like LoopingCall or GLib Timeout) unless you keep track of how much time has passed and change the sleep length on every cycle.

Answer (score -1):

No. sleep does not use cpu. You can test it:

```
from time import sleep
for i in range(10):
    sleep(5)
    print i
```